# Как скрыть страницу неавторизованым пользователям

Tags: php

У меня есть файл index.php в нём сразу как заходишь появляеться форма регестрации и авторизации. Если ты авторизован тебя при нажатии кнопки выдаеться кука и переводит на файл news.php

Как сделать так чтобы если кука выдана с авторизации тебя при заходе на index.php сразу переводило на news.php ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно же. Проверять наличие куки и если она существует и не пуста, то делать редирект на news.php. 
Что-то типа:

```
    if(isset($_COOKIE['user_auth']) && !empty($_COOKIE['user_auth'])) {

    // REDIRECT TO NEWS.PHP

    }
```